# The get in self.request.Get.get() returning more than one object

Tags: django, get

[This is image of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzgWu.png)

and i m getting the error get() returned more than one BoothDetails -- it returned 2! . Please can anyone tell me what to do, and filter do not work in self.request.GET.get()

[The error i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQMCr.png)

Answer (score 0):

DetailView queryset must return only single object, maybe like `id=search_id` or something like that. But your queryset `BoothDetails.objects.all().filter(citizens__Name__icontains=search)` is doing filter based on Name, which I think is similar for more than one citizen so it's returning more than one object.

It depend on your logic how you want to query more specifically and for time being you can try this `BoothDetails.objects.all().filter(citizens__Name__icontains=search).first()`

Comment: It did't worked. when i used .first() it gives the error saying 'BoothDetails' object has no attribute 'filter'.